# Define default culture on site start

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using AttributeRouting and followed the localization example in AttributeRouting.NET and added a culture handler:

```
routes.MapAttributeRoutes(config => {
  config.ConstrainTranslatedRoutesByCurrentUICulture = true;
  config.CurrentUICultureResolver = (httpContext, routeData) => {
    return (string)routeData.Values["culture"] ?? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
  };
  config.UseRouteHandler(() => new CultureRouteHandler());
});
```

I added breakpoints to the CultureRouteHandler and to the resolver.

When I start the site none of the breakpoints is fired ...

So I am not able to select the default culture for the first request.

My CultureRouteHandler is the following:

```
protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext context) {

  String culture = (String)context.RouteData.Values[_culture];

  if (culture == null) {
    culture = "en";
  }

  if (culture != null) {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    context.RouteData.Values[_culture] = culture;
  }

  return base.GetHttpHandler(context);

} // GetHttpHandler
```

How can this be solved?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: you can set a default culture in the web.config. or you want to do it using the `CultureRouteHandler`

Comment: My idea would be in the CultureRouteHandler ... And that is what I I am trying but the handler does not fire when I start my site ... Have no idea why. Do you know why?